# jQuery toggle, changing height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello im trying to get a box from the right to get a width of 100px

But i have the problem when im showing and hiding the box the height changes.
I have a picture to show:
[image]

Like you see the height is getting smaller when it shouldn't anyone know how to stop this?

Comment: Give us some code, Jsfiddle would be better.

Comment: Its just $("#element").toggle(), right now

Comment: @hernanvicente i fixed a jsfiddle but i dont get the problem there :S http://jsfiddle.net/da837/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have your code, but it can be solved by adding

```
yourElement.style.height = normalHeightSize;
```

In JQuery,

```
$('#yourElement').css('height: normalHeight');
```

when the user shows the box, in their click event or whatever happens in the code.  In your case, after `toggle()`.

Comment: I've noticed your answer this morning, and it worked perfectly, thanks!